# How to randomise the placement of a single '0' on the bottom of an empty board, as inputted by the user?

Tags: python-3.x, random

This is part of a Connect4 game in which the program asks the player for the size of the obstructed cells at the start of the game. The obstructed cells won't allow the placement of Connect4 discs throughout the game. However, I'm struggling to randomise the placement of the 1x1 obstructed cell (it can only be placed at the bottom of the board). I also want this obstructed cell to update the `empty_board` (thus, giving me the option to print this new board with the obstructed cell permanently there)

Here's my code so far:

```
# prints an empty board
rows, cols = (6, 7)
arr = [['_' for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

for row in arr:
    print(row)

# asks player for size of desired obstructed cells
for i in range(2):
    while True:
        try:
            width = int(input("state the width of the obstructed cells you wish to have: "))
            height = int(input("state the height of the obstructed cells you wish to have: "))
            if width == 1 and height == 1:
                for row in arr[0]:
                    print(random.seed('0'))
                for row in arr:
                    print(row)
        except Exception:
            print("the inputs must be an integer; less than width 7 and length 8")
```

I've tried using random functions to get it to work. But I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: @derpirscher, hi the "print(random.seed('0'))" is my attempt to using the random functions

Comment: Well, if you just set the `seed` but don't generate any random number (for instance using `random.randint` or similar) then you won't get any results. Try reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)  and the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#examples). And BTW if you want a different random value every time you run your program, you probably shouldn't initialize your random generator with a fixed seed ...

Comment: Ive tried using random.randint('0') to radnomly print a '0' on the bottom row, but now it keeps stating "the inputs must be an integer; less than width 7 and length 8" whenever I input a 1 and a 1

Answer (score 0):

To get a random int from the random package, use `random.randint(min, max)`. eg. `random.randint(0,6)` will give you an integer between 0 and 6 inclusive - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint). Use the value you get from this (n) as your column id and set `arr[0][n] = 0`.

Also, as others have mentioned, do not set the random.seed to a fixed value if you don't want your results to be repeatable. Highly suggest reading the docs for more information.